# How to pass a string to a VB.NET project's function that is referenced by a C# website?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, function

I have the following function in a VB.NET project.  The function has many overloads, but the one I'm trying to use is the shown below:

```
Public Function GetScalar(ByRef commandText As String, ByRef commandType As CommandType) As Object
```

I am trying to use the function in a C# MVC4 website as follows:

```
object isMaintenanceMode = sqlTool.GetScalar("ProcedureName", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

I'm getting the following error (which makes me think that it's finding the correct overload):

```
Error: The best overloaded method match for 'GetScalar(ref string, ref System.Data.CommandType)' has some invalid arguments
```

When I "right-click" on the GetScalar function, and choose to "Go To Definition", Visual Studio brings up the "Find Symbol Results" window.  From here I double click on the function and I am taken to a list of the functions in that class (it's a file that has the keywords [from metadata] appended to it - it doesn't actually exist in any project):

```
public object GetScalar(ref string commandText, ref CommandType commandType);
public object GetScalar(SqlCommand foreignCommand, CommandType commandType);
public object GetScalar(ref string commandText, ref CommandType commandType, ref bool NoTimeOut);
```

So my question is - do you have to do anything special (besides adding a reference to the project) to use a VB.NET project and function inside a C# MVC4 web site?  Also, is there something I am doing wrong in passing the string to the function?  I am new to C# and MVC and am trying to learn as I go.

I have noticed that if I pass `null` into the function as the string, the error goes away.  This obviously isn't a solution because I need to pass in a stored procedure name, but I figured it shows that there is something wrong with the string I'm passing in as opposed to the `CommandType` or the function itself.  I have also tried to create a string variable, set the name there, and pass the variable into the function.  This did not work either.

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like unsafe code, in that it resembles code that would force you send queries to a database server without any mechanism for keeping parameter data separate from sql query string itself. If so, **that's really bad!** It will force you to write code that is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - thanks for the heads up on sql injection.  We have other overloaded functions that accept parameters, but the function I'm currently using doesn't have parameters - we're just passing in the stored procedure name here and it returns a value.

Comment: Good to hear! I tend to recommend building database libraries that _require_ parameter information, even in cases when you have none (just pass an empty collection or similar), to make it hard for new or jr devs to miss that this is something you should be doing, and help you avoid the temptation to do it wrong.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - good suggestion!  Maybe during our next re-write or cleanup we can make this change.  I guess this setup does make it easy to be lazy...

Comment: I wouldn't advocate going over an existing code base for this. But anything new...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the arguments in a variable and use the [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx) keyword here:

```
var commandText = "ProcedureName";
var commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlTool.GetScalar(ref commandText, ref commandType);
```

Better yet, update the VB.NET code to [not use ByRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182146.aspx).

Comment: I learn something new everyday!  Thanks for the link as well, it's worth reading to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the translation of your VB.Net functions in c#. Meaning the c# version of `ByRef` is `ref`. Since your calling project is in c#, you're seeing the equivalent version of your function definition in c#. Your method:

```
Public Function GetScalar(ByRef commandText As String, ByRef commandType As CommandType) As Object
```

in c# is:

```
public object GetScalar(ref string commandText, ref CommandType commandType);
```

To remove the problem, simply add `ref` keyword to your parameters:

```
var pName = "ProcedureName";
var commandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
object isMaintenanceMode = sqlTool.GetScalar(ref pName, ref commandType);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  I marked @nmclean's response as the answer since it came in first...